# How to move the blocks closer together in a vertical timeline?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, timeline

There is this nice code to create a vertical timeline. I am editing it for my own use. However, I tried a lot to make it vertically shorter, but failed. I need to move the blocks vertically upwards so they can fill both sides of the line, instead of having empty spaces at the right or the left of the blocks and take up a smaller vertical area.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

https://codepen.io/codyhouse/pen/FdkEf

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 var $timeline_block = $('.cd-timeline-block');

 //hide timeline blocks which are outside the viewport
 $timeline_block.each(function(){
  if($(this).offset().top > $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75) {
   $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').addClass('is-hidden');
  }
 });

 //on scolling, show/animate timeline blocks when enter the viewport
 $(window).on('scroll', function(){
  $timeline_block.each(function(){
   if( $(this).offset().top <= $(window).scrollTop()+$(window).height()*0.75 && $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img').hasClass('is-hidden') ) {
    $(this).find('.cd-timeline-img, .cd-timeline-content').removeClass('is-hidden').addClass('bounce-in');
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```css
@import "bourbon";

// variables - colors

$main-text: #7f8c97; // main text
$link: #acb7c0; // anchor tags
$background: #e9f0f5; // body background color

$color-1: #303e49; // blue dark
$color-2: #c03b44; // red
$color-3: #ffffff; // white
$color-4: #75ce66; // green
$color-5: #f0ca45; // yellow

// variables - fonts 

$primary-font: 'Droid Serif', serif;
$secondary-font: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

// mixins - rem fallback - credits: http://zerosixthree.se/

@function calculateRem($size) {
  $remSize: $size / 16px;
  @return $remSize * 1rem;
}

@mixin font-size($size) {
  font-size: $size;
  font-size: calculateRem($size);
}

// mixins - border radius

@mixin border-radius($radius:.25em) {
  border-radius: $radius;
}

// layout - breakpoints
   
$S:     320px;   
$M:     768px;     
$L:     1170px;     

// layout - media queries

@mixin MQ($canvas) {
  @if $canvas == S {
   @media only screen and (min-width: $S) { @content; } 
  }
  @else if $canvas == M {
   @media only screen and (min-width: $M) { @content; } 
  }
  @else if $canvas == L {
   @media only screen and (min-width: $L) { @content; } 
  }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */

html * {
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

*, *:after, *:before {
 @include box-sizing(border-box);
}

body {
 font: {
  size: 100%;
  family: $primary-font;
 }
 color: $main-text;
 background-color: $background;
}

a {
 color: $link;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-family: $secondary-font;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

h1, h2 {
 font-family: $secondary-font;
 font-weight: bold;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Modules - reusable parts of our design

-------------------------------- */

.cd-container { /* this class is used to give a max-width to the element it is applied to, and center it horizontally when it reaches that max-width */
 width: 90%;
 max-width: $L; // breakpoints inside partials > _layout.scss
 margin: 0 auto;

 &::after { /* clearfix */
  content: '';
  display: table;
  clear: both;
 }
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main components 

-------------------------------- */

header {
 height: 200px;
 line-height: 200px;
 text-align: center;
 background: $color-1;

 h1 {
  color: $color-3;
  @include font-size(18px);
 }

 @include MQ(L) {
  height: 300px;
  line-height: 300px;

  h1 {
   @include font-size(24px);
  }
 }
}

#cd-timeline {
 position: relative;
 padding: 2em 0;
 margin: {
  top: 2em;
  bottom: 2em;
 }

 &::before {
  /* this is the vertical line */
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 18px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 4px;
  background: darken($background, 5%);
 }

 @include MQ(L) {
  margin: {
   top: 3em;
   bottom: 3em;
  }

  &::before {
   left: 50%;
   margin-left: -2px;
  }
 }
}

.cd-timeline-block {
 position: relative;
 margin: 2em 0;
 @include clearfix;

 &:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
 }

 &:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }

 @include MQ(L) {
  margin: 4em 0;

  &:first-child {
   margin-top: 0;
  }

  &:last-child {
   margin-bottom: 0;
  }
 }
}

.cd-timeline-img {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px $color-3, inset 0 2px 0 rgba(#000, .08), 0 3px 0 4px rgba(#000, .05) ;

 img {
  display: block;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin-left: -12px;
  margin-top: -12px;
 }

 &.cd-picture {
  background: $color-4;
 }

 &.cd-movie {
  background: $color-2;
 }

 &.cd-location {
  background: $color-5;
 }

 @include MQ(L) {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -30px;

  /* Force Hardware Acceleration in WebKit */
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

  .cssanimations &.is-hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
  }

  .cssanimations &.bounce-in {
   visibility: visible;
   @include animation(cd-bounce-1 .6s);
  }
 }
}

@include keyframes(cd-bounce-1) {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  @include transform(scale(.5));
 }

 60% {
  opacity: 1;
  @include transform(scale(1.2));
 }

 100% {
  @include transform(scale(1));
 }
}

.cd-timeline-content {
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 60px;
 background: $color-3;
 @include border-radius;
 padding: 1em;
 box-shadow: 0 3px 0 darken($background, 5%);
 @include clearfix;

 h2 {
  color: $color-1;
 }

 p, .cd-read-more, .cd-date {
  @include font-size(13px);
 }

 .cd-read-more, .cd-date {
  display: inline-block;
 }

 p {
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.6;
 }

 .cd-read-more {
  float: right;
  padding: .8em 1em;
  background: $link;
  color: $color-3;
  @include border-radius;

  .no-touch &:hover {
   background-color: lighten($link, 5%);
  }
 }

 .cd-date {
  float: left;
  padding: .8em 0;
  opacity: .7;
 }

 &::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 16px;
  right: 100%;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  border: 7px solid transparent;
  border-right: 7px solid $color-3;
 }

 @include MQ(M) {
  h2 {
   @include font-size(20px);
  }

  p {
   @include font-size(16px);
  }

  .cd-read-more, .cd-date {
   @include font-size(14px);
  }
 }

 @include MQ(L) {
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 1.6em;
  width: 45%;

  &::before {
   top: 24px;
   left: 100%;
   border-color: transparent;
   border-left-color: $color-3;
  }

  .cd-read-more {
   float: left;
  }

  .cd-date {
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   left: 122%;
   top: 6px;
   @include font-size(16px);
  }

  .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) & {
   float: right;

   &::before {
    top: 24px;
    left: auto;
    right: 100%;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-right-color: $color-3;
   }

   .cd-read-more {
    float: right;
   }

   .cd-date {
    left: auto;
    right: 122%;
    text-align: right;
   }
  }

  .cssanimations &.is-hidden {
   visibility: hidden;
  }

  .cssanimations &.bounce-in {
   visibility: visible;
   @include animation(cd-bounce-2 .6s);
  }
 }
}

@include MQ(L) {
 /* inverse bounce effect on even content blocks */
 .cssanimations .cd-timeline-block:nth-child(even) .cd-timeline-content.bounce-in {
  @include animation(cd-bounce-2-inverse .6s);
 }
}

@include keyframes(cd-bounce-2) {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  @include transform(translateX(-100px));
 }

 60% {
  opacity: 1;
  @include transform(translateX(20px));
 }

 100% {
  @include transform(translateX(0));
 }
}

@include keyframes(cd-bounce-2-inverse) {
 0% {
  opacity: 0;
  @include transform(translateX(100px));
 }

 60% {
  opacity: 1;
  @include transform(translateX(-20px));
 }

 100% {
  @include transform(translateX(0));
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="cd-timeline" class="cd-container">
  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
   <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

   <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h2>Title of section 1</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.</p>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
    <span class="cd-date">Jan 14</span>
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
   <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-movie">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-movie.svg" alt="Movie">
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

   <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h2>Title of section 2</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde?</p>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
    <span class="cd-date">Jan 18</span>
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
   <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-picture">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-picture.svg" alt="Picture">
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

   <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h2>Title of section 3</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, obcaecati, quisquam id molestias eaque asperiores voluptatibus cupiditate error assumenda delectus odit similique earum voluptatem doloremque dolorem ipsam quae rerum quis. Odit, itaque, deserunt corporis vero ipsum nisi eius odio natus ullam provident pariatur temporibus quia eos repellat consequuntur perferendis enim amet quae quasi repudiandae sed quod veniam dolore possimus rem voluptatum eveniet eligendi quis fugiat aliquam sunt similique aut adipisci.</p>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
    <span class="cd-date">Jan 24</span>
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
   <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-location">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-location.svg" alt="Location">
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

   <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h2>Title of section 4</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum aut hic quasi placeat iure tempora laudantium ipsa ad debitis unde? Iste voluptatibus minus veritatis qui ut.</p>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
    <span class="cd-date">Feb 14</span>
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
   <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-location">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-location.svg" alt="Location">
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

   <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h2>Title of section 5</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto, optio, dolorum provident rerum.</p>
    <a href="#0" class="cd-read-more">Read more</a>
    <span class="cd-date">Feb 18</span>
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->

  <div class="cd-timeline-block">
   <div class="cd-timeline-img cd-movie">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/148866/cd-icon-movie.svg" alt="Movie">
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-img -->

   <div class="cd-timeline-content">
    <h2>Final Section</h2>
    <p>This is the content of the last section</p>
    <span class="cd-date">Feb 26</span>
   </div> <!-- cd-timeline-content -->
  </div> <!-- cd-timeline-block -->
 </section> <!-- cd-timeline -->
```

Comment: Side by side or just remove the spacing?

Comment: remove the spacing, I suppose the blocks will be sitting side-by-side

Comment: They won't side side by side, that's a grid system. If you just need to decrease the spacing, you can change margin

Comment: I did try to reduce the margin of the blocks, esp `cd-timeline-block` but it does not work and does not let the blocks sit next to each other.

Answer (score -1):

.cd-container has a max width which is set by breakpoints for the view size and a width of 90%.

Those, specifically- your breakpoints for the container that are limiting the width.

Use your browser debug tools dude.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I am not talking about the width, I am talking about the height. I want to the blocks sit next to each other rather than sitting underneath and making a big vertical space